# Creating plugin in C++ without compiling all QGIS source

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

After some research, I found the only way to create a plugin in C++ is to compile the QGIS source with the plugin created using the "plugin_builder.py" which can be found in the "src/plugins" on the git qgis (https://github.com/qgis/Quantum-GIS/tree/master/src/plugins)

To create a simple plugin which can be add simply by putting the folder of the plugin
in ".qgis/python/plugins" or "C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/python/plugins" the plugin must be written in Python.

Is there a way to create a plugin in C++ without compiling all the QGIS source ?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to build QGIS just to make a C++ plugin.  The only thing you should need to do is include the QGIS headers inside `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\include`

The complied plugins then have to go into `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis-dev\plugins`.  This is the correct place for non python based plugins.

**Note**: I don't build C++ plugins, only Python ones.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I tried your method and the plugin doesn 't appear in the plugin manager

Comment: This can be due to a huge variety of reasons. To get a hint, you could have a look at the debug output using [debug view](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647) and check if there is any output related to your plugin.

Comment: Yeah I think too this can be due to a variety of reason. To make the plugin I use this CMakeLists. Do you think it's a good start ? http://www.filedropper.com/cmakelists

Comment: Finaly the plugin was visible in Qgis but it's strange when I change a little bit the code and even if it's compile well, sometimes it's dissapear. Qgis checks if the plugin runs well when it starts ?